# How to make sure figure fits all artists added to axes?

Tags: matplotlib

Consider the following toy code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

def draw_circle_arrangement(ax, drawing_origin, drawing_space, scale, num_circles, box_height, box_width):
    bw = drawing_space*(box_width*scale)

    drawing_origin[0] = drawing_origin[0] - bw*0.5

    circle_diameter = drawing_space*scale
    circle_radius = 0.5*circle_diameter
    y_delta = np.array([0., circle_diameter])
    x_delta = np.array([circle_diameter, 0.])

    cell_origin = drawing_origin + np.array([circle_radius, circle_radius])
    y_delta_index = 0
    x_delta_index = 0

    for ci in range(num_circles):
        cell_patch = mpatches.Circle(cell_origin + y_delta_index*y_delta + x_delta_index*x_delta, radius=circle_radius, color='k', fill=False, ls='solid', clip_on=False)
        ax.add_artist(cell_patch)

        if y_delta_index == box_height - 1:
            y_delta_index = 0
            x_delta_index += 1
        else:
            y_delta_index += 1


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# each tuple is: number of circles, height of box containing circles, width of box containing circle
circle_arrangements = [(10, 2, 5), (3, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1)]
data = np.random.rand(3)
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax.plot(np.arange(3) + 1, data, marker='o')
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
scale = 1./10.

for i, ca in enumerate(circle_arrangements):
    do = np.array([1.0 + i, -0.2])
    nc, bh, bw = ca
    draw_circle_arrangement(ax, do, 0.8, scale, nc, bh, bw)
```

When run, it produces output like so:
[image]

As you can see, the circle arrangement patches are getting cropped at the bottom of the figure? How can I make sure `matplotlib` is providing enough space for all drawings on the figure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get patches to draw with equal aspect ratio even though associated axis does not have equal aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45128513/how-to-get-patches-to-draw-with-equal-aspect-ratio-even-though-associated-axis-d)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar These questions are not duplicates. They use the same toy code, but ask two entirely different questions: 1) how to get the patches to draw with an aspect ratio different form the parent axes, and 2) how to make sure all the patches are fit within the figure area.

Comment: Perfectly right, my apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a "taller" figure and manually set the axes position so as to leave yourself plenty of space.  When you want to save the figure, use `bbox_inches='tight'` to crop out the unnecessary whitespace.

```
# Figure width, height in inches
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.4,8))
# [xo,yo,w,h] in normalized fig coords
ax = fig.add_axes([.125,.4,.75,.5])     

circle_arrangements = [(10, 2, 5), (3, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1)]
data = np.random.rand(3)
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax.plot(np.arange(3) + 1, data, marker='o')
ax.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
scale = 1./10.

for i, ca in enumerate(circle_arrangements):
    do = np.array([1.0 + i, -0.2])
    nc, bh, bw = ca
    draw_circle_arrangement(ax, do, 0.8, scale, nc, bh, bw)

plt.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

### Something that does not work

I was going to suggest `plt.tight_layout()` but that does not work.  [The documentation's first caveat](https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html#caveats) states that it:

> only considers ticklabels, axis labels, and titles. Thus, other
>   artists may be clipped.

You'll find that with your example code, in which there are no axis labels or xticklabels, that the axes is blown up to fill essentially the entire figure window and the circles are pushed completely out.